# JavaScript - Create a new method that finds the largest sum of consecutive entries in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, integer

I need to create a method that finds the **largest sum** of consecutive entries in an array given a group size.  It should take an `array` and the interval size as inputs and should return both the largest sum and the index of the first entry in the group.

For example, in the following `Array [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]` given a group size of `2` the result would be a maximum sum of 3 and a position of 6.

How would one Complete this?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?  And, is this homework of some kind?

Comment: Are you aware of JSfiddle?  show us your first attempt at this!

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't post any code my answer will be general.

The easiest way will be to loop through the array and finding sum of current digit with n consecutive digits, up until the currentDigitIndex<=array.length-n, in this loop you should compare currentDigitSum with the currentMaxSum and store which ever is larger in the currentMaxSum (also store the maxSumPositionIndex).

While solving this problem you should account for a things like: what if array length is equal to 1 or 0, what if an array has negative integers, what if group size will be larger than array length, what if your array has 2 or 3 equally large sums...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I came up with.  It works in MOST scenerios, not all, therefore the answer can be improved on.

```
Array.prototype.maxGroupOf = function (size) {
  max = -Infinity;
  indexSpot = 0;
  len = this.length - size + 1;
  add = function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
  };
  this.forEach(function (x, y) {
    if (y > len) return;
    b = this.slice(y, y + size).reduce(add, 0);
    if (b > max) {
      max = b;
      indexSpot = y;
    }
  }, this);
  return {
    sum: max,
    position: indexSpot
  };
};

console.log([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2].maxGroupOf(2));

---Output---
Object {sum: 3, position: 6}
```